# How do I add my value to this button href

Tags: php

I want to add custom link that is stored in a value inside a php button. How do I do it?

I am trying to get this sorted how ever its not doing it, it just returns nothing or sometimes returns the current page link instead. I am looking towards adding my $lnk to this code in href section.

This is what I have:

```
echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type=btnnn-class onClick=location.href="" .$lnk value="Contact Buyer">';
```

Where `$lnk` is my link inside of it.

Comment: once the page is loaded, go to the page source and check what is there in the html. It should be like this : onClick=location.href="'.$lnk.'".

Comment: <input class="btnnn-class" onclick="location.href=&quot;$lnk&quot;" value="Contact Buyer" vk_18e18="subscribed" type="btnnn-class">

Comment: <input class="btnnn-class" onclick="location.href=$lnk" value="Contact Buyer" vk_15ad3="subscribed" type="btnnn-class">         without the quatation in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al Fonce told correct answer and described wel
He forget one double quotes after $lnk . '\'

```
echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type="btnnn-class" onClick="window.location.href=\'' . $lnk . '\'" value="Contact Buyer">' ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is several typos in your code : you did not open and/or close quotes when needed. You have too surround your classes with double quotes and your `onClick` value too. Inside it, the `location href` is a string too that should be inside quotes.

Both php and javascript allow single and double quotes to delimitate a string, but you should use only double quotes for html attributes.

So:

- Use single quotes `'` for the whole `echo` statement (but varaiables are not interpreted inside single quotes),
- Use double quotes `"` for the html attributes.
- Use single quotes `'` for the javascript value, and escape it (becasue they are inside another php single quoted string).

The code:

```
echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type="btnnn-class" onClick="window.location.href=\'' . $url . '\'" value="Contact Buyer">' ;
```

Or use double quotes for php and espace the html attributes ones, the variable will be interpreted:

```
echo "<input class=\"btnnn-class\" type=\"btnnn-class\" onClick=\"window.location.href=$url\" value=\"Contact Buyer\">" ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo '<input class="btnnn-class" type="btnnn-class" onClick="window.location.href=\'$lnk\'" value="Contact Buyer">' ;
```

Because of the quotes, you are facing the problem.

Comment: This won't work. You copy-pasted my answer and include the variable in the single-quoted string, but the variable will not be interpreted, because of these single-quotes.

Comment: Sorry to say but I didn't copy your answer. I have my own brain and thinking power and I don't need to copy anyone's answer. Cheers :)